# Printing the binary form of bytes in java, "==" not working?

Tags: java

Firstly I know you can use methods to print the binary representation in java, I just wanted to do it myself for fun.

I've managed to do it for integers just fine with the code below.

```
public static void printBinary(int n) {

    int mask = n;
    mask = mask ^ ~mask;    //make sure mask is 1111...
    mask = mask << 31;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

        int test = mask & n;

        if (test == mask) {

            System.out.print("1");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("0");
        }

        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        mask = mask >>> 1;
    }

}
```

I thought bytes wouldn't be much different so I made this method for bytes:

```
public static void printBinary(byte n) {
    byte mask = n;
    mask = (byte) (mask ^ ~mask);
    mask = (byte) (mask << 7);


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        byte test = (byte) (mask & n);

        if (test == mask) {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("0");
        }

        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        mask = (byte) (mask >>> 1);
    }
}
```

The result I get for this, no matter what value of of n is just 0000 0000. How come the boolean operator == doesn't seem to be working as intended? Or perhaps that isn't the problem as I suspect.

Any ideas?

Comment: First idea is to step through it with a debugger and look at your values, make sure they are doing what you expect.

Comment: I'm currently using just the console. However printing out the mask  on each iteration of the for loop I get -128,-64,-32,-16,-8,-2,-1. Seems like the unsigned shift right simply isn't working as expected on a byte.

Comment: That doesn't quite seem correct.  You should get -128, +64, +32, +16, +8, +4, +1

Comment: Exactly, it works perfectly fine with the integer method, strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually that this line doesn't do what you intend:

```
mask = (byte) (mask >>> 1);
```

Arithmetic is on integers, so the `>>>` takes place after sign extension. We can rewrite that expression this way, to make the problem more clear:

```
// assume that mask is initially 1000 0000

int maskInt = (int) mask;   // maskInt is 1111 1111 1111 ... 1111 1000 0000
maskInt = maskInt >>> 1;    // maskInt is 0111 1111 1111 ... 1111 1100 0000
mask = (byte) maskInt;      // mask is 1100 0000
```

. . . with an extra leading `1`. So now you would only print `1` if the *two* high bits of `n` are *both* set.

To fix this, you need to "mask out" the 24 high bits of the implicit `maskInt` by writing `& 0b1111_1111`. Adding that into the above snippet, we'd have:

```
int maskInt = (int) mask;         // maskInt is 1111 1111 1111 ... 1111 1000 0000
maskInt = maskInt & 0b1111_1111;  // maskInt is 0000 0000 0000 ... 0000 1000 0000
maskInt = maskInt >>> 1;          // maskInt is 0000 0000 0000 ... 0000 0100 0000
mask = (byte) maskInt;            // mask is 0100 0000
```

Putting that back in expression form:

```
mask = (byte) ((mask & 0b1111_1111) >>> 1);
```

Comment: Oh, I totally understand what's going on now, thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly now, I'm not too what the 0xFF means though? I understand what it does, but not how, or what the notation means.

Comment: @NylePudding: Oh, sorry. `0xFF` is an integer literal (=source-code representation of an integer constant), just like `12` or `1_000_000`, but the `0x` prefix means it's in hexadecimal (base-16) instead of the usual decimal (base-10). `F` is the hex symbol for 15, so `0xFF` is 15*16+15 = 255. Since you're not already used to hex, you might prefer to use binary, by writing `0b1111_1111` instead. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to set "mask = n" as the first step, since all you really care about is that mask = ~0;

Actually, you don't care that mask = ~0. You only care that the highest bit is set.  which means you want mask = 1 << (numBits-1);

Actually... What you want is to loop through each bit in reverse.

```
for (int i = numBits-1; i >= 0; --i) {
   System.out.print((value & (1 << i) == 0) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Actually, what you want is to not reinvent the wheel.

```
System.out.print(Integer.toString(n, 2));
```

Comment: Re: "what you want is to not reinvent the wheel": Nonsense. The very first sentence of the question was "Firstly I know you can use methods to print the binary representation in java, I just wanted to do it myself for fun." If you don't think that people should learn how things work, then this probably isn't the site for you!

Comment: Fair enough. I skimmed over that part a little too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the mask to be zero for the lower 7 bits, so when you `&` this with a number which is between 0 and 127, you will always get 0.

If you have a mask of say -128 or 0b11..11 1000 0000 and you compare it with a value of 0 this should always be `!=`

Something which should help is to step through your code in your debugger to see what each line of code does.